# Convert Excel Password Protected file to a Normal Excel File With Password?

Tags: excel, password-protection

I have a use case where an Excel file is the data source, and it is sent to us password protected.  I have downstream processes that expect an unlocked Excel file.  I have the password.

I am looking for a way to create an unlocked version of the Excel file from the locked version using the given password, in a scripted fashion, to automate the process.

Does anyone know a way to apply the password to the Excel file and then save a new unlocked version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a "Password to Open" then the following VBS might help get you started.

```
' Create an Instance of Excel
Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
' Load your file with given password
Set Workbook = App.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx",,,,"yourpassword")
' Optional - Allow Overwrite without prompt
App.DisplayAlerts = False
' Save your file, using the existing filename but reset/clear password
Workbook.SaveAs Workbook.FullName,,"",""
' Close and Quit
Workbook.Close
App.Quit
Set App = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks @NickSlash, I will give it a go and revert, much obliged.  This is a Password-to-Open case, so it looks promising.

Comment: This worked perfectly, really helpful, selected as the solution, really appreciate it!